# How to keep mapbox-gl-draw features aligned with the perspective?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-draw

I am trying to draw rectangles in Mapbox that stay upright, while the map gets rotated (and are drawn upright, when the map is already rotated).

I've used the following code to draw rectangles: https://github.com/dqunbp/mapbox-gl-draw-rectangle-restrict-area

However, when I rotate the map, the rectangle rotates too (likewise, when the map is already rotated, the rectangles will be tilted too). Is there any option to keep the rectangle in the upright orientation while the map rotates?

[Example of a rectangle rotating with the orientation of the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqWhd.png)